# How to calculate probability of a sentence given probabilities of its words?

Tags: python, list, numpy, dictionary

I'm working in Python, attempting to write a loop that will calculate the probability of a sentence by taking the product of each word in the sentence's probability. I have a dictionary that contains thousands of words as keys and their probabilities as values. The issue I'm having is that my current attempts seem to calculate a sentence level probability of 1 no matter what. Here's what my code looks like at the moment:

```
sentence = "This is a short and boring sentence."
## we'll say that "probs" is the dictionary that contains all my word-probability pairs
## this is the loop I'm trying to run my sentence through:
problist = []
for x in sentence:
    problist += probs[x]

## my thinking is that the code above will create a list of each word in the sentence's probability
## then I can find the product of the list using numpy
import numpy
sentprob = numpy.prod(problist)
```

However, like I said, this code always seems to return a probability of 1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Among many other issues, `for x in sentence` will give you letters.

Comment: I would recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is:

```
for x in sentence:
    problist += probs[x]
```

`x` here isn't a word, but a letter. Meaning you are searching in your dictionnary the probability of `T`, `h`, `i`...
As for why the result is `1`, the [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html) says:

> The product of an empty array is the neutral element 1

Try using this:

```
for x in sentence.split():
    problist += probs[x]
```

Note that the `.` at the end of the sentence is still a problem as the last world would be `sentence.`. You should remove all `.`, `,`, `?`... etc.